# Review all scripts that run after sshing into a machine

Tags: ssh, zsh

Is there a way to review everything that runs when I ssh into a machine?

Somehow when I ssh, it starts out with `zsh`, which is my default shell, but then later changes to fish shell. Want to find out where the fish shell is being called and delete that line.

Answer (score 1):

Yan can add `set -vx` very early in your various `zsh` startup scripts `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`, etc. If the swicth to `fish` occurs even earlier, try the same with the zsh startup script in `/etc`.